# Почему окурок - бычок?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Здравствуйте!
Интересно, кто-нибудь знает, почему окурки часто называют бычками? Рыбы-бычки - это понятно: они массивные, толстые и где-то их можно сравнить с быками. А вот при чем тут окурки?
Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Часто окурки называют «бычками» . Происхождение этого слова связано со строительством Беломорско-Балтийского канала. В официальных документах времён постройки Беломорканала он часто именовался аббревиатурой БК. Часто так же его называли и заключённые, задействованные на его постройке. После начала выпуска известных дешёвых папирос «Беломорканал» , приуроченных к сдаче канала в эксплуатацию, аббревиатурой «БК» заключённые стали называть и марку этих папирос. Так как фонетически «БК» произносится как «бэка» , в разговорной речи часто звучали такие фразы, как: «дай бэка» , «оставь покурить бэка» . Постепенно слово «бэка» переосмыслилось людьми, незнакомыми с происхождением слова, или не прошедшими через систему ГУЛАГа, как «оставь покурить быка (или бычка, в случае маленького окурка)» , по созвучию слов бэка-быка. Окурок сигареты или папиросы соответственно стал именоваться «бычок».    На  просторах  интернета  в  основном  тиражируется  эта  версия.

Comment: а стоит ли бычка заключать в кавычки? Спасибо.